# Writing to console without delays

Tags: c, console, stdout

I'm writing a command line game that should work at 4-40 FPS (will choose later). But, I have a problem. Drawing an "image" consisting of 1920 colored characters using putchar() takes 0.2-0.3 seconds, and I can see my image getting drawn line by line. However, for example, in Firefox, I can draw 64000 RGB pixels on canvas almost in less than tenth of a second.

Is there a way to avoid that delay, and is that delay forced by console or that's really how long it takes to process output?

Comment: Console games of this sort have been around for a long time.  Have you considered looking at the prior art to see how they solved this problem?  This one might be a good place to start:  http://code.google.com/p/ascii-game-engine/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `putchar`. Make a buffer full of your characters, representing the screen state, and use `write` to send your buffer all at once to stdout, then flush it.

For example:
`write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, buffer_size); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Tried this, can't see custom color, do you have a solution?

Comment: To change custom color just use `fputs("\033[40m", stdout)` for example.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, instead just writes strange characters. Is there any way to make your way SetConsoleTextAttribute-friendly?

Answer (score 2):

You should assemble your output string in memory and write it in one peace e.g using printf