# C++ Writing to console without delays

Tags: c++, buffer, output

I'm looking for a C++ solution to an already existent question: [Writing to console without delays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777210/writing-to-console-without-delays).

Basically, I'm trying to output a large block of text to a console window without getting that "typing" delay. As in, even though it's very fast, you can still see it being written to the screen line by line. Since the entire screen can immediately change colors, I know it's not a screen refresh issue, but rather how the output is being done.

If you need more details, read the other thread, the OP of that one explained the issue much better than I can.

Right now, I'm storing everything in a `stringstream` buffer, but how to output it immediately is where I'm stuck.

Thanks.

UPDATE: The issue seems to be that VS2013 doesn't like to do an immediate output. When I compiled my code with Code::Blocks, I'm getting the desired output.

```
stringstream s;
// ...
cout << s.str() << flush;
```

Comment: Please tag the appropriate platform.

Comment: What delays? What is stored in the stream? Why do you need to copy it to a buffer? What do you need to output? Where do you need to output?

Comment: Please show your code. Why aren't you just using `cout <<` to write your output, instead of writing to a `stringstream`?

Comment: try calling `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` before outputting anything (as long as you aren't using any C output functions like `printf`). If you need more help you'll have to show your code.

Comment: @Barmar, see the other thread. It suggested a buffer.

Comment: In that question, the original code was writing one character at a time with `putchar()`. If you're writing whole lines or more, you don't need to use that solution.

Comment: It is operating system specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, now you have to output stringstream contents to the console, eg:

```
stringstream s;
... // fill s with data
cout << s.str()
```

Please remember that the size of data must be whole screen (i. e. 80x24), otherwise it is not going to look pretty.

You may also consider putting flush() - which will trigger immediate output to the screen, rather than buffering.

```
cout << flush();
```

EDIT:
As you have mentioned that it still is slow, I'd recommend using [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) - however this solution is not very portable.

**Another thing causing this issue might have been the compilation flags used in VS**

Comment: No different between that and just using cout through the entire writing process.

Comment: This is not true, since if you were using cout everywhere, you'd probably create screen part by part, whereas here you put the entire thing at once.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that I'm still seeing the delay. Even with << flush added at the end.

Comment: Ok, I didn't expect that, then my answer is rubbish. Usually, people use curses for these kind of things, but it's not very portable (eg. to Windows)

Comment: Hmm, strangely there's only a delay when compiled with VS. Code::Blocks seems to work just fine.

Comment: Maybe it's about compilation flags?

Comment: Who knows? I typically only use VS for debugging anyways, so I don't care that much.